# How to get height from the top of the div (not window) for each item and apply to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to apply margin top based on tab click. When TAB 4 is clicked the content need to be in same position from top.

[image]

Comment: Nice! And what is your problem? What did you try?

Comment: $("element").top()

Comment: Don't see the problem, neither do I really know what your question is here, but here is an idea: If you have the top of the wrapping div (parent of TAB 4?) and the top of the clicked div (i.e. TAB 4), it should be easy for you to figure out the top of the content div of Tab 4.

Comment: I tried this var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;

Comment: `$("#myDiv").offset().top`

Answer (score 0):

You should get the to position of the clicked tab. When you have that, you can apply a style to the content. You can obtain the position of the tab with [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). That will return the left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width and height properties of the element.

One ceavat:

> Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of
>   the viewport.

So you should take the scroll position into account. You can obtain that by [Window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY).

The position of the element from the top would be:

`element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY`

With that information you can apply a style like:

```
var tabTopOffset = myTabElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
// var myContent = document.getElementById('#my-tab');
var myContent = document.querySelector('.my-tab'); 

myContontent.style = tabTopOffset + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

    // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
    $('.tabs').each(function(){
      $('.tab', this).click(function(){
        var fromTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
        var newhref = href.substring(1);
        $('#'+ newhref).css('margin-top', fromTop);
      });

    });

});
```